# deploy web application with laravels voyager admin panel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, voyager

i developed a Website using **Laravel 5.5** and **Voyager Admin panel**.
Now i want to deploy my website to a DigitalOcean server.

While developing I created tables via Voyagers Database Tool.
I also set my relations between the tables there. This worked very well in my developing environment.

I pushed my final code of the website to a git repo and now i want to clone it on the liveserver.

**Now my question:** 
Do I have do **recreate** all tables again via the voyager admin panel and set the relations between the tables new again? Because i didn't create **migrations** for the tables and only created tables through the voyager backend.Or will they automatically be set if i clone the repo and make an `php artisan voyager:install` or an `php artisan migrate`?

Would be nice if anybody already gained some experience with deploying voyager applications.

Best regards

Answer (score 3):

If you still didn't find any solution, you can try: [Laravel Migrations Generator](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator).

It will automatically generate migrations from an existing database schema.

Then you can do:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Hope, it will solve your problem.

Comment: You can use the following package for new laravel versions:
https://github.com/kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator